# how to make read more with slide down effect for content with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am generating a news section with php and I want to make continue reading like blog posts. When a user clicks continue reading i will make all the news article slide down. 
Here is the code I have:

```
<?php foreach ($news as $newsItem) : ?>
    <div class="news-item" id="news-<?php echo $newsItem->id; ?>">
        <a href="#" class="image"><img src="/path/to/my/image" 
            alt="<?php echo $newsItem->photo; ?>" /></a>
        <h4><a><?php echo $newsItem->title; ?></a></h4>
        <p><?php echo $newsItem->content; ?></p>
        <a class="read-more" href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>front/site/news">Read more</a>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

---

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.read-more', function(){
    // what should happen here?
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your jQuery snippet should look like:

```
$(function() { // Only when DOM is ready
  $('a.read-more').on('click', function() {
    // Your code
  }
});
```

Then, you need to decide whether you use lazy-loading of content or not. Two solutions :

1. You simply load the whole article and hide the *read-more* section on page load.
2. You use AJAX to load content from your database (using your news id)

Comment: I need to use the 1st solution I think because I need to hide like 50 characters of a post and when I click read more it should slide down the rest of the content

Comment: pretty close with what I want to achieve, but I want to have all the content loaded and with jquery only display the 1st part and hide the 2nd part and when click read more to slide down the 2nd part

Comment: It is actually working on Chrome and IE, can't try on Firefox. But I found that the ellipsis is not removed from the content, so here is a new version: http://jsfiddle.net/9Z4au/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ($news as $newsItem) : ?>
   <div class="news-item" id="news-<?php echo $newsItem->id; ?>">
    <a href="#" class="image"><img src="/path/to/my/image" 
        alt="<?php echo $newsItem->photo; ?>" /></a>
    <h4><a><?php echo $newsItem->title; ?></a></h4>

    <!-- echo first part of the article here -->
    <p><?php echo $newsItem->content-summary; ?></p>
    <div class="hidden-more">

       <!-- echo the remainder of the article here -->
       <p><?php echo $newsItem->content-remaining; ?></p>   
    </div>
    <a class="read-more" href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>front/site/news">Read more</a>
   </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

the css

```
div.hidden-more{
    display:none;
}
```

the jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('a.read-more').on('click', function(){
         //find local hidden area and show it with nice slide effect
         $(this).parent().find('div.hidden-more').slideDown();
    });
});
```

Comment: yes ok, but how do I generate 1st part of the article and the rest of the article...i do not want to save it like that in the database, I want to do it with jquery to show only the 1st part of the content and when clicked to show the rest

Comment: you do it with php, use substrings for concatenation. I am not a big php guy, but you should be able to take a variable and limit the number of characters to 50, then use that same variable from the same db record and cut off the first 50.